# Paste text without formatting on Excel 16.82

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

There are existing questions about pasting without formatting into earlier versions of Excel - for example [Is there a way to make paste as text only the default action in Office 2016?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287159/is-there-a-way-to-make-paste-as-text-only-the-default-action-in-office-2016)

I have gone through a number of these and none work.  Here is the dialog for one of the first suggestions:  there is no option to paste without formatting :

[image]

Is there *any* way to do this on recent versions of Excel for MacOS? I am on `16.82` on `Sonoma 14.3`.